# Edit files in server using text editor

Tags: linux, terminal

I was wondering, is there a way I can edit files inside a live linux server using a text editor? I am able to edit using the `nano` command but that is not very friendly. Can I achieve the same using an editor.

Comment: What do you mean by "using a text editor"? `nano` is a text editor.

Comment: There are ways to do this kind of thing but, if you're often in a position of logging into Linux servers remotely, I would respectfully suggest that it's worth becoming very familiar with a least one console-based editor -- nano, vi/vim, emacs, whatever.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

vi is an editor. If you mean graphical editor, then it depends. At first glimpse, you have two options: A) Open the file using some file share (nfs, samba, ftp?) on your client computer using your favourite editor, or B) Use some ssh client which is capable of "tunneling" an X connection (putty?) and use an editor running on the server machine, displaying GUI on your client (which acts as an X host).

Answer (score -1):

You can install a better editor, like [`vim`](http://vim.org/) or [`emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) on your Linux server.

You could also install X-client editors like `gedit` (and many others) and use `ssh -X` to access your server. You need some [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server in front of you (on your laptop).

Comment: Or install a VNC server on the Linux machine, and run an X desktop remotely using a VNC client. VNC clients are widely available, and may be easier to set up, especially for folks who aren't particularly familiar with Linux, than a remote X server.